# Symfony2: Custom configuration root

Tags: php, symfony

My application consists of multiple bundles that are named like `HelloWorldAdminBundle`, `HelloWorldUserBundle`, `HelloWorldDemoBundle`. This results in a configuration root like `hello_world_demo`, `hello_world_user` and `hello_world_demo`. I want that the configuration roots of my bundles are `helloworld_demo`, `helloworld_user` and `helloworld_admin`. At that point I have to mention that this is not really a technical problem, but more of an aesthetic problem.

I have tried to implement a custom extension and register it in the Bundle:

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);

    $container->registerExtension(new HelloworldDemoExtension());
}
```

The extension:

```
...
class HelloworldDemoExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'hello_world_demo';
    }
}
```

and finally the configuration:

```
...
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('helloworld_demo');
        ...
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

I followed the instructions [How to expose a Semantic Configuration for a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/extension.html), however when I add an item to `config.yml` I get the following error:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "helloworld_demo"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. It works exactly as I described it in the question, however, a default extension (with the name of the bundle) **must** exist.

I now have an empty, but existing extension named HelloWorldDemoExtension (with the alias `hello_world_demo` and additionally I added DemoExtension (with the alias `helloworld_demo`) and it works.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by overriding [`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle#getContainerExtension()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Bundle/Bundle.php#L72).

This method automatically creates and returns an instance of `ExtensionInterface`, and also checks if the extension's alias (which you can specify by implementing `getAlias` in your extension class, as per [Carlos Granados'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1557651/carlos-granados) answer) conforms to the naming convention.

So by overriding the `getContainerExtension()` method in your bundle class, and simply return an instance of your extension class, you can bypass the check and the `LogicException`.

This is what your bundle class would look like:

```
<?php

namespace HelloWorld\Bundle\UserBundle;

use HelloWorld\Bundle\UserBundle\DependencyInjection\HelloWorldUserExtension;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class HelloWorldUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        if (null === $this->extension) {
            $this->extension = new HelloWorldUserExtension();
        }

        return $this->extension;
    }
}
```

And, of course, don't forget to add this to your extension class:

```
/**
 * The extension alias
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAlias()
{
    return 'helloworld_user';
}
```

**Warning**: I'm not sure why this check was added to the `getContainerExtension()` method. There might be a very valid reason, and you might encounter problems when following the above steps. However, I haven't had any problems with it so far.

**Edit**: Also see: [Symfony2: Some things I don't like about Bundles](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2013/10/symfony2-some-things-i-dont-like-about-bundles/). This blog article comes with the same solution as my answer. Also, see [this pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/3894/files#diff-b81c044e869806d3811de25c35bc3fc7R51) for Symfony's documentation, which also describes the same method. This makes me believe that it is safe to do so without having to expect side effects.

Comment: This is ugly but i guess if you really want to break symfony's conventions, that's the way to go. The cleanest way must be to name your bundle correctly anyway :-).

Comment: @AlainTiemblo naming the bundle correctly isn't always possible - `CMSIP2LocationBundle`.

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#extension-conventions) says:

> When creating an extension, follow these simple conventions:
>
> - The extension must be stored in the DependencyInjection sub-namespace;
> - The extension must be named after the bundle name and suffixed with    Extension (AcmeHelloExtension for AcmeHelloBundle);
> - The extension should provide an XSD schema.

I am not really know if you need define own `build` and `getAlias` methods. If you need it then `getAlias` method should return this same value as you define in root node. So it should be `helloworld_demo` probably instead of `hello_world_demo`

Comment: No. As far as I understood the documentation the `getAlias` method is used by Symfony to relate the extension to the bundle. Since the name of extension no longer provides any hint of the bundle, the alias is used. **Edit:** This is explained at the bottom of the Semantic Configuration documentation page: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#extension-conventions

Comment: And regarding the first part. I am aware of these conventions and I want to break them for the sake of aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

From the book
"In this case, the extension class must also implement a getAlias() method and return a unique alias named after the bundle (e.g. acme_hello). This is required because the class name doesn't follow the standards by ending in Extension.
Additionally, the load() method of your extension will only be called if the user specifies the acme_hello alias in at least one configuration file. "

So, this alias IS the root configuration name. Change your code to

```
public function getAlias()
{
    return 'helloworld_demo';
}
```

And it should work

Comment: `[LogicException]                                                                                                                                                              
  The extension alias for the default extension of a bundle must be the underscored version of the bundle name ("hello_world_demo" instead of "helloworld_demo")`

Comment: mmm... so, I guess that the only solution left is to rename your bundles to HelloworldDemoBundle, etc...